# Compare elements every X items

Tags: jquery, for-loop, while-loop, each, rows

first question!

I have a list of say 50 divs in columns of 4 and every row I want to compare details.

```
<div class="all-items">
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <!--new for/while here-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <div class="item">Hello</div><!--store height for e.g.-->
    <!--new for/while here-->
</div>
```

etc

I just can't figure out how to do this in jQuery!

I've tried using a for loop for every 4 items, but using an each within that is proving pointless, I thought maybe a while but couldn't get that working properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Could you make more clear what the result is you want to achieve?

Comment: essentially I want to create a responsive equal height per row system as none of the others are examples i've found are working properly for me. But if I am able to loop through each product in each row I figure I could also store any other data on the items that i might need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you correctly but.. what about this:

```
var rowSize = 4;
$(".all-items > .item").each(function(index, object){       
    if(index % rowSize == 0){
        //the current item is the first one in the new row
        //do stuff for a new row
    }       
    //do stuff for each item        
});
```